# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' exporting csv in pandas python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, unicode

I've created a pandas DataFrame in python 2.7

When I try to export it as csv with the function

```
outcome.to_csv("/Users/john/out_1.csv")
```

I get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 191: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can export it? and If I can't how do I go to position 191 and remove that character?

Many thanks

EDIT:

The dataframe looks like:

```
0         CA0037381      LSAL:G97715947CF      CA0037381LSAL:G97715947CF   
1         CA0037381      LSAL:G97717947CF      CA0037381LSAL:G97717947CF   
2         CA0037684          HINT:13426CF          CA0037684HINT:13426CF   
3         CA0037679     WAVE:JLA0901BRNCF     CA0037679WAVE:JLA0901BRNCF   
4         CA0037373  HUGR:5026134836266CF  CA0037373HUGR:5026134836266CF   
5         CA0037601       WAST:WGCH23BLCF       CA0037601WAST:WGCH23BLCF   
6         CA0037601        WAST:WG19800CF        CA0037601WAST:WG19800CF   
7         CA0037318         ENDO:ALBARINO         CA0037318ENDO:ALBARINO   
8         CA0037319        HEAV:XYG001ACF        CA0037319HEAV:XYG001ACF   
9         CA0037319     TWOS:4782-20TWOCF     CA0037319TWOS:4782-20TWOCF   
10        CA0037320          SERE:BD635/A          CA0037320SERE:BD635/A   
11        CA0037321          CASG:12285CF          CA0037321CASG:12285CF
```

Note: this is only a tiny fraction since it is 16330 rows x 372 columns. the dataset is very sparse (i.e. many blank cells)

Comment: Try `outcome.to_csv("/Users/john/out_1.csv", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: Tried. Now I get: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 105174: invalid continuation byte

Comment: what about `utf-16'`, can you post the data

Comment: with utf-16 I keep getting: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 105174: invalid continuation byte. I cannot post the data is a dataframe with 16330 rows x 372 columns

Comment: Your problem is probably related to that when you *read* your dataframe, you do not read it with the proper encoding. Can you show how you read your dataframe and maybe a cleartext example of what it contains?

Comment: You cannot decode unicode to utf8 unless the data in the dataframe is proper unicode. For it to be proper unicode, you have to read it with the right encoder. Trying to encode latin-1 with an utf-8 codec will sometimes pass silently, but the unicode data you end up with is actually corrupt.